# How can I pair, connect and trust a Bluetooth device with Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to piece together how I can get Bluetooth working with python;)

I've found some code, but it's giving me errors.

```
from gi.repository import GLib
from pydbus import SystemBus
from pprint import pprint

SCAN_TIME = 15
DEVICE_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.Device1'
adapter_path = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_address = 'AC:9B:0A:18:53:81'
dev_path = f'{adapter_path}/dev_{device_address.replace(":", "_").upper()}'

remove_list = set()

def stop_scan():
    adapter.StopDiscovery()
    mainloop.quit()


def clean_device(rm_dev):
    try:
        adapter.RemoveDevice(rm_dev)
    except GLib.Error as err:
        pass

def on_iface_added(path, interfaces):
    if DEVICE_INTERFACE in interfaces:
        on_device_found(path, interfaces[DEVICE_INTERFACE])

def on_device_found(device_path, device_props):
    address = device_props.get('Address')
    if address == device_address:
        stop_scan()

def pair_device():
    dev = bus.get('org.bluez', dev_path)
    dev.Trusted = True
    dev.Pair()


bus = SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get('org.bluez', adapter_path)
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')
mngr.onInterfacesAdded = on_iface_added

clean_device(dev_path)

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

GLib.timeout_add_seconds(SCAN_TIME, stop_scan)
adapter.SetDiscoveryFilter({'DuplicateData': GLib.Variant.new_boolean(True)})
adapter.StartDiscovery()

mainloop.run()

pair_device()
```

, but I get this error. From searching, I'm just missing some slashes, but I can't figure out which;)

```
$ connect-mdr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b0ef/.nimble/bin/connect-mdr.py", line 55, in <module>
    pair_device()
  File "/home/b0ef/.nimble/bin/connect-mdr.py", line 35, in pair_device
    dev = bus.get('org.bluez', dev_path)
  File "/nix/store/xq9mvc45n5xccgaj55p2pcxak9c3bsij-python3-3.10.12-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydbus/proxy.py", line 59, in get
    return CompositeInterface(introspection)(self, bus_name, object_path)
  File "/nix/store/xq9mvc45n5xccgaj55p2pcxak9c3bsij-python3-3.10.12-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydbus/proxy.py", line 118, in CompositeInterface
    raise KeyError("object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()")
KeyError: 'object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()'
```

Any pointers as to what can be wrong?

Comment: You might want to add some `print` statements as debug messages to make it clearer what is happening. My speculation is that the `Discovery` isn't finding the expected device and that is why the `pair_device` is failing. You might want to have `bluetoothctl` running in a different terminal to see what that is reporting as your script is run.